# Запись в cooke при клике на ссылку(кнопку) JS

Tags: php, javascript, cookie

Добавляет модальное окно в куки, тем самым показывает один раз, пока куки не удален из хранилища, а php проверяет если есть куки то не показывать модаль, если нет, показать модаль.

Подскажите как сделать так что бы модальное окно открывалось, но куки были сохранены только при нажатии на кнопку(или ссылку) в этом модальном окне.

Код:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['modal'])) {
 "Модальное окно"
}


<script>
    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        var expires;

        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        } else {
            expires = "";
        }
        document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/";
    }
    createCookie('modal', '1', 30);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброй ночи.
Например так

```
<a href="#" onclick="createCookie('modal', '1', 30); return false">test link</a>
```

размещаете эту ссылку в модальном окне и убираете вызов функции вне ссылки.

```
<script>
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;

    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Не работает. Дело в том что мой код уже помещает модаль в куки, и ваша ссылка, дублирует это действие. Мне же надо что бы модальное окно открывалось, но не было помещено в куки пока я не нажму эту кнопку

Comment: Вы написали, что надо, чтобы cookies были сохранены после нажатия на кнопку или ссылку. Размещаете ссылку в модальном. Где именно дублирует? Что именно не работает?

Comment: Пример работы сейчас: Открывается модаль -> срабатывает скрипт JS и записывает в куки -> php после перезагрузки страницы проверяет есть ли куки под именем modal, если есть то не показывать модаль, если нет показать модаль.                               А надо так: Открывается модаль-> нажимаем кнопку(ссылку) -> срабатывает скрипт и записывает в куки -> php после перезагрузки страницы проверяет есть ли куки под именем modal, если есть то не показывать модаль, если нет показать модаль.

Comment: Мой пример работает. При клике по ссылки устанавливается cookie. Какой результат Вы ожидаете?

Comment: А надо так: Открывается модаль-> нажимаем кнопку(ссылку) -> срабатывает скрипт и записывает в куки -> php после перезагрузки страницы проверяет есть ли куки под именем modal, если есть то не показывать модаль, если нет показать модаль. То есть мне не надо добавлять в куки модаль пока не нажата кнопка

Comment: а с вашей ссылкой получаеться что, сначала срабатывает мой скрипт и добавляет модаль в куки, потом я нажимаю вашу ссылку и происходит тоже самое, модаль повторно записываеться в куки

Comment: уберите вызов createCookie('modal', '1', 30); в своём коде и оставьте только в ссылке, тогда код будет срабатывать только после клика по ссылке. ведь это же и так ясно.

Comment: охх значит я что–то не понял, спасибо теперь все хорошо)